# Add item in Arrays

Tags: c

I got a problem when I try to add element to array and I always got **the itemID already exists** I try to solve it but I couldn't
this is my Function

```
int AddNewItem(){
    FILE* f = fopen("items.txt", "a");
        if(f == 0) {
                printf("file is not present :\n");
                return 0;
        }
        int ItemID,ItemQuantity,PricePerUnit, i = 0,flag = 0;
        int ItemI[10], ItemQ[10],Price[10];

        while(fscanf(f,"%d%d%d",&ItemI[i],&ItemQ[i],&Price[i])>0){
                ++i;
        }
        printf("Enter itemID: ");
        scanf("%d",&ItemID);
        for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
                if(ItemI[i]==ItemID)
                {
                        flag = 1;
                        printf("the itemID already exists\n");
                        break;
                }
                else{
                    ItemI[i+1]=ItemID;

                }
            }

        printf("Enter The price per unit ");
        scanf("%d",&Price[i]);

        fclose(f);
        return ;
}
```

thank you
**This is my file**

1007 5 30

1004 4 10

1003 3 20

1002 2 10

1006 4 40

1005 5 50

1001 1 70

1008 6 20

1010 4 90

1009 3 10

Comment: How many records is there in the file you read? Less than `10`? *More* than `10`?

Comment: ***And*** (more importantly) what if you read *less* than ten records from the file? What are the values of the *remaining* uninitialized array elements? Don't go using uninitialized data, its contents is *indeterminate*.

Comment: Your statement `ItemI[i+1]=ItemID` appears to change the ID of the *next* element in the array to match what you're looking for. So it will always be found on the second time through the loop (if it's not found on the first loop).

Comment: Can you show us what's in `items.txt`?

Comment: 10 items in the file

Comment: I added now @MattSpinks

Answer (score 1):

That's because:

```
            if(ItemI[i]==ItemID)
```

Assuming this statement is false on first iteration. 'else' will be executed:

```
            else {
                ItemI[i+1]=ItemID;
            }
```

So ItemI[1] is set to be ItemID. And on the next iteration, when 'i' is equal to 1, the "if" statement always becomes true. That's why it prints "the itemID already exists"

Comment: but it will be false if the itemID already exists and it will go to else ,, I am right ?

Comment: it may be false when "i" is 0. Then it goes to "else" and sets: ItemI[i + 1]=ItemID, So, on the next iteration it will be true, because you set it here to be true

Comment: Oh, I understand ,, but I try many ways but it didn't give me a correct result,, may you edit the code for me if you can so I can understand it very well, Thank you

Comment: Nope, I don't know what you're coding. I just spotted the bug

Comment: `for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
                
                if(ItemI[i]==ItemID)
                {
                        flag = 1;
                        printf("the itemID already exists\n");
                        break;
                }
            }
                if(flag==0)
                {
                        ItemI[i+1]=ItemID;
                        printf("Enter The price per unit ");
            scanf("%d",&Price[i]);
                }`

Comment: But the file if I kept as **appended** it will not give me a correct result ,, and if I change it to **Reading** it will give correct result !! Why ?

Comment: When you open it in **appended** mode, you won't be able to read the file.
You need to open it in **Readig** mode. It's explained in "man fopen"